# How to terminate an executing program once keyboard is pressed

Tags: c, printf, output, ascii, curses

Here is my code, my goal for this stage is creating an animation of ASCII, terminate it once any character is entered. I use `getch()` for this stage but it seems not to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <curses.h>

int main() {
    int i, j, ms = 250;    
    const char *a = "*";
    struct timespec delay;
    delay.tv_sec = 0;
    delay.tv_nsec = ms * 1000000L;
    while(1) {
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            printf("%c", a[i]);
            fflush(stdout);
            nanosleep(&delay, NULL);
            printf("\b");
        }
        if(getch() != -1)break;
        //printf("%c,%d\n",buffer,buffer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does _not work_ mean? What happens instead?

Comment: You need to enable no-delay mode of getch(), or it will block to wait for a user input. You also use `a[i]` for i = 0..3, but `a` has just 2 characters inside, not 4: '*' and '\0'.

Comment: well the problem is whatever i entered, the program just keep executing and not stop.

Comment: Don't use `-1`, use `EOF` to detect end-of-file.  You need to end your input for an `EOF` to be returned by `getch`.  On a Unix system you can type `^D` to achieve this.  With Windows, well, presumably there's some way to do it.

Comment: How do you invoke the compiler?

Answer (score 0):

Before using **any** curses function, you need to call the initsrc function, manual say:

> `#include <curses.h>`
>
> `WINDOW *initscr(void);`
>
> **Description**
>
> initscr is normally the first curses routine to call when initializing
>   a program.
>
> The initscr code determines the terminal type and initializes all
>   curses data structures. initscr also causes the first call to refresh
>   to clear the screen. If errors occur, initscr writes an appropriate
>   error message to standard error and exits; otherwise, a pointer is
>   returned to stdscr.